# Importing a lazy-loaded module with routes in a module with a route breaks routing

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

Our angular 4.3.6 application has lazy-loaded modules, such as Fleet, Maintenance, Car, etc.

My top-level app router looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'fleet', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fleet',
        loadChildren: "./modules/fleet.module",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'car/:id',
        loadChildren: "./modules/car.module",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'maintenanceProgram',
        loadChildren: "./modules/maintenanceProgram.module",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      }
}
```

We do have a *shared* module with generic components (we have lots of them) used throughout the application. There are, however, some components like modals which are shared only by the `MaintenanceProgram` and the `Car` modules, but not used anywhere else.

In an effort to keep the shared module reasonable, I include these once-reused components only in the `MaintenanceProgram` module, export them, and import the `MaintenanceProgram` module into the `Car` module to have access to the exported components.

Both the `Car` and `MaintenanceProgram` modules have the following embedded child routes invoked in their respective `@NgModule.imports[]`:

Car:

```
const CarModuleRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: CarComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: CarComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
]);
```

and Maintenance Program:

```
const MaintenanceProgramModuleRoutes = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: MaintenanceProgramComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
]);
```

This is obviously not the correct approach either

1. to child routing, or
2. to module transclusion

**because when I load the Car route, I get the Maintenance Program's default route**.

I have tried:

1. Changing the order of the import of `MaintenanceProgramModuleRoutes` and `CarModuleRoutes` in `CarModule`'s `@NgModule.imports[]`,
2. Removing the empty path from CarModule.

*Is the only solution to create *another* shared module that contains the shared components without a router, or is there another, more elegant way to do this?*

This is a reduced example, we actually have many routes and hundreds of components which are reused only twice or three times. This problem will surely persist into the future as the application grows, so I need a scalable and maintainable solution. Creating tens or more extra shared modules is just infeasible.

Comment: i think what your are getting into is circular dependency , Module A uses B, and B uses C . but again C uses A. i had answered such a question today may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000427/2708210) helps

Comment: here both will be called for `''` const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'fleet', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '',

Comment: Hi @RahulSingh, I have `--show-circular-dependencies` enabled in ng-cli and didn't get a report for this. I'll double check..

Comment: @AniruddhaDas That's not where my problem is. When I land at the application *root* (the root `path:''`) I get the Fleet page. When I navigate to `/car/:id`, I get the maintenance program.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Or perhaps that is my problem, but if it is, I don't understand what the effect of it is or how to solve it.

Comment: @msanford Is there a solution ?

Comment: shouldn't it just be `car` for your top-level app router rather than `car/:id`? You specify id in the child routes

Comment: @AndrewAllen Not a bad suggestion as a best practice. Incidentally, `car:/id` _does work_ in our case because it's kinda-sorta not really a child route: there's nothing else under `car/`. Feel free to provide an answer though and grab that bounty! If not maybe I'll post our eventual solution (but I'm now on another project so have to dig it up.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, when creating a shared module, there is no need to care about modules which uses a little part of the shared module, because Angular's tree-shaking will keep only the used code from an imported module, and remove the rest.

I've prepared a minimal project to demonstrate it: https://github.com/youkouleley/Angular-treeshaking-demo

This project has two lazy modules: `AModule` and `BModule`. Both of these modules import `SharedModule`. `SharedModule` exports three components:

- `AComponent` which is used in `AModule` **only**
- `BComponent` which is used in `BModule` **only**
- `BothComponent` which is used in `AModule` **and** `BModule`

Here is what you'll get when `ng build`ing this project in production mode and opening the `4-es2015.<hash>.js` file:

```javascript
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([[4], {
      KImX: function (n, l, u) {
        "use strict";
        u.r(l);
        var t = u("8Y7J");
        class a {
          constructor() {}
          ngOnInit() {}
        }
        var r = u("phyl");
        class o {}
        var c = u("pMnS"),
        s = t.gb({
            encapsulation: 0,
            styles: [[""]],
            data: {}
          });
        function b(n) {
          return t.sb(0, [(n()(), t.ib(0, 0, null, null, 1, "p", [], null, null, null, null, null)), (n()(), t.rb(-1, null, ["a works!"]))], null, null)
        }
        function i(n) {
          return t.sb(0, [(n()(), t.ib(0, 0, null, null, 1, "app-a", [], null, null, null, b, s)), t.hb(1, 114688, null, 0, a, [], null, null)], function (n, l) {
            n(l, 1, 0)
          }, null)
        }
        var p = t.eb("app-a", a, i, {}, {}, []),
        e = u("gJxL"),
        f = u("SVse"),
        h = u("iInd"),
        d = u("PCNd");
        u.d(l, "AModuleNgFactory", function () {
          return v
        });
        var v = t.fb(o, [], function (n) {
            return t.ob([t.pb(512, t.j, t.T, [[8, [c.a, p, e.a]], [3, t.j], t.u]), t.pb(4608, f.i, f.h, [t.r, [2, f.o]]), t.pb(1073742336, f.b, f.b, []), t.pb(1073742336, h.l, h.l, [[2, h.q], [2, h.k]]), t.pb(1073742336, d.a, d.a, []), t.pb(1073742336, o, o, []), t.pb(1024, h.i, function () {
                  return [[{
                        path: "a",
                        component: a
                      }, {
                        path: "both",
                        component: r.a
                      }
                    ]]
                }, [])])
          })
      },
      PCNd: function (n, l, u) {
        "use strict";
        u.d(l, "a", function () {
          return t
        });
        class t {}
      },
      gJxL: function (n, l, u) {
        "use strict";
        var t = u("8Y7J"),
        a = u("phyl");
        u.d(l, "a", function () {
          return s
        });
        var r = t.gb({
            encapsulation: 0,
            styles: [[""]],
            data: {}
          });
        function o(n) {
          return t.sb(0, [(n()(), t.ib(0, 0, null, null, 1, "p", [], null, null, null, null, null)), (n()(), t.rb(-1, null, ["both works!"]))], null, null)
        }
        function c(n) {
          return t.sb(0, [(n()(), t.ib(0, 0, null, null, 1, "app-both", [], null, null, null, o, r)), t.hb(1, 114688, null, 0, a.a, [], null, null)], function (n, l) {
            n(l, 1, 0)
          }, null)
        }
        var s = t.eb("app-both", a.a, c, {}, {}, [])
      },
      phyl: function (n, l, u) {
        "use strict";
        u.d(l, "a", function () {
          return t
        });
        class t {
          constructor() {}
          ngOnInit() {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Note that the `BComponent` from the `SharedModule` is missing from the `AModule` chunk. Sames goes for `BModule` chunk that excludes `AComponent`.

Also, note that this behavior is obtained when setting `commonChunk` to `false` in the build options. This option allows you to choose between:

- `false`: Bundle the needed parts of the `SharedModule` directly into the lazy modules that imported it. **Pro:** Even loading time between lazy modules. **Con:** Some code from `SharedModule` is duplicated between lazy modules chunks, higher app size overall
- `true` (default): Have a common chunk that contains the parts of the `SharedModule` which are used **at least** by two lazy modules (the rest is bundled into the lazy modules themselves). **Pro:** No duplicated code, lower app size overall. **Con:** The first lazy module is slower to load (it loads the common chunk even if the current route doesn't need it)

As a conclusion, Angular build provides optimizations for the `SharedModule` with `commonChunk` set either to `true` or `false` (depending on your context) you don't really have to worry about your `SharedModule` size. Thus, you don't have to try strange patterns like you did, with hybrid modules fulfilling the feature module role, and the shared module role at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in  top-level app router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'fleet', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fleet',
        loadChildren: "./modules/fleet.module#FleetModule",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'car/:id',
        loadChildren: "./modules/car.module#CarModule",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'maintenanceProgram',
        loadChildren: "./modules/maintenanceProgram.module#MaintenanceProgrammodule",
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
      }
}
```

> Your needed change: add `#module_class_name` in end of router path.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I use to handle big shared module is to create a module per component. In your example, you should created a `ModalModule`, declare and export your `ModalComponent`. It should look something like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ModalComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule, // any modules that your modal need
  ],
  exports: [
    ModalComponent,
  ]
})
export class ModalModule {}
```

Then simply include `ModalModule` in your CarModule imports, and `MaintenanceProgramModule` imports.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CarComponent],
  imports: [ CarRoutingModule, ModalModule ],
})
export class CarModule
```

You should create module for all shared component, and only include each shared component's module in the route that need it. It do help greatly reduced the size of each page.